# jquery addClass before code and removeClass after code don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$("#add_city").click(function() {   
    **$("#gif_loader").addClass("overlay");**
    var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance( 'tab_citta' );
    var aSelectedTrs = oTT.fnGetSelected();
    var totAdded = 0;
    $.each(aSelectedTrs, function(i, item) {
        totAdded = totAdded + $(this).children().eq(1).html() * 1;
        addRowAddedCity($(this).children().eq(0).html(),
                        "<span class='val_or right' style='text-align:right;'>"+$(this).children().eq(1).html()+"</span>",
                        "<input type='text' class='new_val right' value='" + $(this).children().eq(1).html() + "' />");         
        var pos = oTableAddedCity.fnGetPosition($(this).get(0));
        oTableCity.fnDeleteRow(pos);            
    });         
    oTT.fnSelectNone();
    $('#tot_city_sel').html( $('#tot_city_sel').html() * 1 + totAdded );
    **$("#gif_loader").removeClass("overlay");**
});
```

The code between add and remove class take 3 seconds but I don't see the new class change ...
It seems like the add and remove class are both executed after the inside code.

Comment: maybe you should not add and remove the same class for this instance. Try the code without removeClass and see if the added class still is after executing. and then work your way from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have to do with browser repaint call.

As you might already know the browser will do only one task at a time, mean either it will execute the javascript or refresh the ui(repainting the browser).

In this case since the thread is busy executing the script it may not find time to repaint the ui with the added class information.

One possible solution I can suggest is to use a timeout to give the browser enough breathing space to update the ui as given below

```
$("#add_city").click(function() {   
    $("#gif_loader").addClass("overlay");
    setTimeout(function(){
        var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance( 'tab_citta' );
        var aSelectedTrs = oTT.fnGetSelected();
        var totAdded = 0;
        $.each(aSelectedTrs, function(i, item) {
            totAdded = totAdded + $(this).children().eq(1).html() * 1;
            addRowAddedCity($(this).children().eq(0).html(),
                            "<span class='val_or right' style='text-align:right;'>"+$(this).children().eq(1).html()+"</span>",
                            "<input type='text' class='new_val right' value='" + $(this).children().eq(1).html() + "' />");         
            var pos = oTableAddedCity.fnGetPosition($(this).get(0));
            oTableCity.fnDeleteRow(pos);            
        });         
        oTT.fnSelectNone();
        $('#tot_city_sel').html( $('#tot_city_sel').html() * 1 + totAdded );
        $("#gif_loader").removeClass("overlay");
    })
});
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much. I just have to add 100 ms of timeout. So the correct solution for me is: setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 100); With a less amount of time still doesn't work. Thanks a lot.